# Why does my flutter app not run on Android Studio virtual device emulator?

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I use a Windows pc and I'm learning about developing flutter apps. I keep getting this error message when i try to run the flutter app on the emulator (Android studio) but the app runs fine if I use Chrome.[Error message: "Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEl1J.png)

I tried running flutter doctor to see if there was anything wrong but everything was fine. I set everything up exactly the way it was in the tutorial video but i still do not know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I strongly suggest that you need to configure an Android Emulator in Android Studio IDE. The procedure: `Android Studio` > `Tools` > `Device Manager` > `Virtual` > `Create Device`, then follow the tips/guidance to do so. Below is my Android Emulator.

[image]

Secondly, once you have configured/created the emulator, you can start to run/debug your flutter app in `Android Studio` or `VSCode` by choosing the emulator device you just created.

Note: no virtual device was created, no android emulator was run.

**An Instruction on Launching an iOS Simulator on Xcode.**

The procedure is easy to launch the iOS Simulator, here are the process you may pay attention to:
1.You need to download the `Xcode` from Mac App Store;
2.After you've installed Xcode, open the `ios` folder in the Flutter root project, choose `Runner.xcworkspace` to open if it exists, otherwise choose `Runner.xcodeproj` to open;
3.Choose a simulator to launch your app, see my screenshots.
[image]

Comment: I’ve already done this. The problem arises when it’s time to run/debug the app. After selecting the emulator in VsCode, I get an “Exception in thread “main” java.net.UnknownHostException” message in the debug console

Comment: If it is hard to launch an Android Emulator, I strongly suggest you can use of iOS Simulator which is really good for us to test and hot-reload. The iOS Simulator is more better than the Android Emulator, and iOS Simulator is less troubling us.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Could you recommend any I could use. It would be helpful if you could attach tutorial links to help me set them up properly

Comment: Yes, the procedure is not difficult to launch the iOS Simulator, here are the process you may pay attention to:
1.You need to download the `Xcode` from Mac App Store;

Comment: Please see my updated answer above.

Comment: I use a Windows pc and code in VsCode. Can I still get Xcode or it’s different for windows?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot use Xcode on Windows, unless you run a Virtual Machine (like VMware) on your Windows, and then you can run a macOS inside the Virtual Machine, finally the Xcode can be installed on your macOS.  But based on my experience, Xcode runs on VMware's macOS will be having the very slow speed. Do your own discretion.